# Запуск node сервера на arduino

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

Недавно открыл для себя `Arduino`. Для логики использовал **Node js** и **Johnny-five** и **PubNub** для **IoT**. Однако, для того что бы моргать светодиодом/принимать данные с термометра и тому подобное, мне нужно при подключенном usb шнуре к компьютеру открывать командную строку и запускать node сервер. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно задействовать что бы моя плата была **только под питанием, а сервер запускался либо на самой arduino** или может еще каким-то способом о котором я не знаю. Просто я бы хотел себе домашнюю метеостанцию, а необходимость постоянного подключения к ПК - меня не радует. Заранее прошу прощения за абстрактный вопрос, но какой-то внятной информации в сети, я не нашел.Исключительно уже готовые решения без технического описания. Я только учусь. Спасибо.

Comment: Для node.js ардуина слишком маленькая, посмотрите что-то посеръезней, например [orange pi zero](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepizero/) (около 1000р, с WiFi, можно запускать ubuntu).

Comment: Спасибо. Если честно, мне приходила уже эта мысль в голову, но я просто надеялся на то, что может есть какой-то способ о котором я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве сервера могу посоветовать выбрать плату разработчика NodeMCU ESP8266. Программировать ее можно как на фреймворке Arduino так и на Espruino. Советую выбрать Espruino: будет очень легко перенести код с Node. Далее можно использовать NodeMCU как саму метеостанцию или же передавать на нее данные (например с помощью радио модулей NRF) c вашей Arduino, а потом отправлять на сервер.